# How can I switch off IPv6 ND RA transmissions in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I am working on Ubuntu 11.04. I want to switch off the IPv6 ND RA transmissions. How can I do this?

Comment: I suspect that having answered the first part of your question you may want to edit this question so that the title more accurately reflects what you're looking for.

Comment: IPv6 ND has a [whole list of functions](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/aug/28/ipv6-neighbor-discovery/) associated with it.  What specifically are you trying to disable?

Comment: @Mike: I want to switch of Router Discovery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn off Router Advertisement acceptance via these sysctls:

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=0 (where eth0 can be any interface)
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't want IPv6 enabled at all. If you don't have IPv6 ND, that's the equivalent of not having ARP in IPv4. So IPv6 will not be usable.

If you really want to disable IPv6 temporarily, issue the command:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

You could add this to a system startup file in order to disable it on each boot, or use your distribution's supported method to tweak sysctl variables. (On Ubuntu that would be creating a file in `/etc/sysctl.d` with the content `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`.)

If you want to disable other aspects of IPv6, run the command `sysctl -a | grep ipv6` to see what options you have. You could, for example, disable the acceptance of DAD (duplicate address detection) packets, or the acceptance of RA (router advertisement) packets.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable radvd on the advertising machine. The configuration file is usually in `/etc/radvd.conf`

Comment: What if the OP can't guarantee that all advertising routers have been removed from the network? (Someone might have set up a malicious "router" that tries to intercept IPv6 traffic, the router might not be under the OP's control, etc)

Comment: @Mike, wireshark is the standard tool to answer your question.  My answer makes the assumption he is capable of tracing traffic back to the source.

Comment: By the way, [here are some good tools](http://www.remlab.net/ndisc6/) (other than Wireshark, which will of course do the job) for troubleshooting ND in IPv6.